# applications take longer to run on domain computers

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, windows-domain

We have Server2012 r2 domain with folder redirection of Desktop, Documents, and Appdata.

In some of my windows 10 pc's applications like Outlook, other Office programs, and Acrobat Reader take forever to load if run as user but if run as admin it starts up normally with no problem.

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer for timeouts or issues communicating with network resources? This sounds as though the applications are expecting to be able to communicate with something the regular user accounts don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by running sfc /scannow in elevated powershell interface on user computer.